# Can’t open “.jar” files after Java update on macOS

Tags: java, jar

Ever since I updated my Java version (around 3 updates ago) it stopped opening `.jar` files on my computer. I get a pop-up that says:

> “The java jar file could not be launched check the console for possible error messages.”

The console says:

[image: Print screen with the log from the console]

I am using Java version  10.0.2, and I am completely stuck. It was working just fine before the updates, I was able to create `.jar` files and open them just fine, but now even if I download external  `.jar` files from the internet I keep getting this message.

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .jar file is an applet.  The last version of Java to support applets is Java 8.

From [Oracle's Java SE Support Roadmap](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html):

[image: support table]